# VB.Net Determining Control at Bottom of the GroupBox

Tags: vb.net

If I have a groupbox with 7 controls for example:

```
GroupBox
Label 
ComboBox 
Label 
ComboBox 
Label
TextBox 
Button 
Label
ComboBox
```

If I want to remove the control with the largest Location.Y (the bottom most control in the groupbox), do I have to loop through each control until I have found the largest, or is there any other way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to loop.

```
Dim lastControl As Control = GroupBox1.Controls.Cast(Of Control).OrderByDescending(
                               Function(x) x.Bottom).First
```